# Вставка JSON в MySQL (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, json, парсер

Здравствуйте. 
Не получается вставить JSON в MySQL в C# (MySql.Data)
JSON правильный, но в ItemsXML содержится XML файл. На всякий случай прикрепил скриншот с ошибкой. Посоветуйте, как решить проблему?

```
{
    "NickName": "231312312312",
    "height": "1",
    "fatness": "0",
    "gender": "male",
    "head": "default_head_12",
    "current_class": "0",
    "experience": "0",
    "pvp_rating_points": "0",
    "banner_badge": "0",
    "banner_mark": "0",
    "banner_stripe": "0",
    "game_money": "0",
    "cry_money": "0",
    "crown_money": "0",
    "ItemsXML": ["<item id='974606037' name='rds07' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='21647380' equipped='29' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' /> ", "<item id='974606038' name='mk01' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='163840' equipped='8' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' /> ", "<item id='974606039' name='claymoreexplosive' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='5242880' equipped='16' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' />", "<item id='974606040' name='explosivegrenade' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='5411845' equipped='29' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' /> ", "<item id='18446744073709551309' name='kn01' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='4329476' equipped='29' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' />", "<item id='18446744073709551241' name='pt05_shop' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='3247107' equipped='29' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' /> ", "<item id='18446744073709551262' name='ar02_shop' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='1' equipped='1' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' />", "<item id='18446744073709551325' name='sr02_default' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='1024' equipped='4' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' />", "<item id='18446744073709551276' name='smg04_shop' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='1048576' equipped='16' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' />", "<item id='18446744073709551269' name='shg01_default' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='32768' equipped='8' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' />", "<item id='18446744073709551230' name='df01' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='65536' equipped='8' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' /> ", "<item id='18446744073709551342' name='ap01' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='2' equipped='1' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' /> ", "<item id='18446744073709551294' name='ak01' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='2097152' equipped='16' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' />", "<item id='18446744073709550015' name='medic_helmet_08' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='393216' equipped='8' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' /> ", "<item id='18446744073709549990' name='medic_kneepads_02' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='294912' equipped='8' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' /> ", "<item id='18446744073709550026' name='sniper_helmet_08' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='12288' equipped='4' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' /> ", "<item id='18446744073709550022' name='sniper_kneepads_02' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='9216' equipped='4' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' />", "<item id='18446744073709550019' name='soldier_helmet_08' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='12' equipped='1' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' /> ", "<item id='18446744073709550024' name='soldier_kneepads_02' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='9' equipped='1' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' />", "<item id='18446744073709550008' name='engineer_helmet_08' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='12582912' equipped='16' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' /> ", "<item id='18446744073709549989' name='engineer_kneepads_02' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='9437184' equipped='16' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' />", "<item id='18446744073709550029' name='shared_hands_08' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='7576583' equipped='29' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' /> ", "<item id='18446744073709550010' name='shared_pants_02' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='19482642' equipped='29' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' />", "<item id='18446744073709549981' name='shared_jacket_02' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='14070797' equipped='29' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' /> ", "<item id='18446744073709549986' name='shared_shoes_10' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='17317904' equipped='29' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' />", "<item id='18446744073709550006' name='shared_vest_13' attached_to='0' config='dm=0;material=default' slot='18400273' equipped='29' default='1' permanent='0' expired_confirmed='0' buy_time_utc='0' expiration_time_utc='0' seconds_left='0' /> "],
    "Notifications": ""}
```

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И где скриншот?

Comment: @ИльяПетров  тексты ошибок надо не скриншотом вставлять.... очень желательно их также в текстовом виде прикреплять.......... Выложи код, который ты выполняешь

Comment: Скорее всего вы где-то не заэкранировали кавычки.